# How to update multiple instances of a model with Provider

Tags: flutter, model, provider

So, I have a model called passengerTemplate which is basically a widget with buttons for incrementing and decrementing the value like the picture bellow :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ndT19.jpg)
and and i made 2 instances of it but the value is being the same in both widgets
I am using provider to update the values here are my files:

passengerTemplate :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:transportation_application/Notifiers/notifier.dart';
import 'package:transportation_application/my_flutter_app_icons.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import '../Notifiers/passenger.dart';

// import '../notifier.dart';
class pasTemp extends StatefulWidget {
  String name;
  int dispNum;
  String requiredAge;
  late int number;
  late int min;

  pasTemp(
      {required this.name,
      required this.requiredAge,
      required this.number,
      required this.min,
      required this.dispNum});

  @override
  State<pasTemp> createState() => _pasTempState();
}

class _pasTempState extends State<pasTemp> {
  late Color minuscolor = Colors.blue;

  // passenger pa = passenger();
  void increment() {
    if (widget.number < 9) {
      setState(() {
        widget.number++;
      });
    } else {
      setState(() {
        widget.number = 9;
      });
    }
    // notifyListeners();
  }

  void decrement(int min) {
    if (widget.number > min) {
      setState(() {
        widget.number--;
      });
    } else {
      setState(() {
        widget.number = min;
      });
    }
    // notifyListeners();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final provider = Provider.of<passenger>(context, listen: false);
    print('Passengers build');
    return ChangeNotifierProvider<TextProvider>(
      create: (context) => TextProvider(),
      child: Provider(
        create: (context) => TextProvider(),
        child: SafeArea(
          child: Container(
            width: 400,
            height: 70,
            child: Stack(
              children: [
                Positioned(
                    top: 12,
                    right: 20,
                    child: Column(
                      children: [
                        Text(widget.name,
                            style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                        Text(widget.requiredAge,
                            style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 15, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold))
                      ],
                    )),
                Positioned(
                    top: 25,
                    left: 60,
                    child: Text(
                      '${widget.number}',
                      style:
                          TextStyle(fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                    )),
                Positioned(
                  top: 12,
                  left: 80,
                  //  counter > 0
                  //         ? () {
                  //             setState(() {
                  //               counter = counter > 0 ? counter - 1 : 0;
                  //               minuscolor = Colors
                  //                   .blue; // Set the color to blue when the counter is greater than zero
                  //             });
                  //           }
                  //         : () {
                  //             setState(() {
                  //               counter = 0;
                  //               minuscolor = Colors
                  //                   .grey; // Set the color to green when the counter is zero
                  //             });
                  //           },
                  child: IconButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        decrement(widget.min);
                      },
                      icon: Icon(
                        size: 30,
                        MyFlutterApp.minus_circled,
                        color: Colors.blue,
                      )),
                ),
                Positioned(
                  top: 12,
                  child: IconButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        increment();
                      },
                      // () {
                      //   setState(() {
                      //     counter++;
                      //   });
                      // }

                      icon: Icon(
                        size: 30,
                        Icons.add_circle_outlined,
                        color: Colors.blue,
                      )),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

passenger:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:transportation_application/Templates/passengerTemplate.dart';

class passenger extends ChangeNotifier {
  late int _number;
  int dispNum = 0;
  passenger(this._number);
  int get number => _number;
  void increment() {
    if (_number < 9) {
      _number++;
    } else {
      _number = 9;
    }
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void decrement(int min) {
    if (_number > min) {
      _number--;
    } else {
      _number = min;
    }
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

I tried to instantiate two Providers in main but nothing changed

Comment: Remi (the author of the Provider package) suggests that new projects might want to start with his RiverPod instead.  Provider is in maintenance mode, while RiverPod continues to add new cool features constantly.